# Checkpoint timeout due to backpressure

Tags: apache-flink

We have a long-term running job to sink records into Elasticsearch. Because the ES cluster is doing routing at midnight, the sink will sometimes fails. We handle those failure and re-add those failed inserting action into queue and continue to insert them. However we found that the backpressure for the source is becoming higher and checkpoint operation finally get timeout. The job will get stuck and dont progress anymore.

Any idea to solve this problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is not to output to the ES first, to determine if the back pressure occurs when writing to the ES.
It is recommended to refer to this article: https://blog.csdn.net/dtzly/article/details/101006064